# bash script use cut command at variable and store result at another variable

Tags: bash, variables, loops, ping, cut

I have a *config.txt* file with IP addresses as content like this

```
10.10.10.1:80
10.10.10.13:8080
10.10.10.11:443
10.10.10.12:80
```

I want to *ping every ip* address in that file

```
#!/bin/bash
file=config.txt

for line in `cat $file`
do
  ##this line is not correct, should strip :port and store to ip var
  ip=$line|cut -d\: -f1
  ping $ip
done
```

I'm a beginner, sorry for such a question but I couldn't find it out myself.

Comment: `for line in cat file` will run twice... once with `line=cat` and once with `line=file`.  I don't think that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The awk solution is what I would use, but if you want to understand your problems with bash, here is a revised version of your script.

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

##config file with ip addresses like 10.10.10.1:80
file=config.txt

while read line ; do
  ##this line is not correct, should strip :port and store to ip var
  ip=$( echo "$line" |cut -d\: -f1 )
  ping $ip
done < ${file}
```

You could write your top line as

```
for line in $(cat $file) ; do ...
```

(but not recommended).

You needed command substitution `$( ... )` to get the value assigned to $ip

reading lines from a file is usually considered more efficient with the `while read line ... done < ${file}` pattern.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 not more efficient, but safer: `for line in $(< file)` will iterate over each *word* in the file, not each *line*.

Comment: @yourmother, note the use of quotes around the variables here: vital to protect whitespace in the values.

Comment: Note the ip can be extracted with `ip=${line%%:*}` without having to call echo|cut.

Comment: @glennjackman `while IFS=: read -r ip _; do` can also be used.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks! Sorry my answer took so long but I was messing around with how to make a good USB Linux version.
With Universal-USB-Installer btw ^^

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid the loop and cut etc by using:

```
awk -F ':' '{system("ping " $1);}' config.txt
```

However it would be better if you post a snippet of your config.txt